# How did Future Trunks learn the Spirit Bomb Technique?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In episode 66 of Dragon Ball Super, Trunks gathers energy from the life forms and forms a medium-sized Spirit Bomb while fighting Zamazu. I don't recall Future Trunks seen Goku use Spirit Bomb in the anime, I'm not sure though. How did he managed to do it if he didn't taught by anyone or possibly didn't even seen or knew it in the first place? Moreover, he didn't even concerntrate to gather the energy like Goku did everytime.

[image]

Comment: My answer may be proven wrong once the current arc officially ends but I'd say it's about a 70%chance of me being correct. If the next episode proves me wrong I will promptly delete my answer.

Comment: Personally, I think the creators had Super Android 13 movie in mind, where Goku does a spirit bomb in front of Trunks and he absorbed it, Trunks also makes a genki dama and absorbed it, and since Trunks learnt Mafuba by watching, and also probably the Galick-Ho and using God Ki by watching Vegeta. Now people is going to say the movie is not canon, but the fact is the series isnt only taking ideas from the manga. For example, the super saiyan blue kaioken was invented in the series and reused later, not only "filler" and the final kamehameha idea comes from a videogame

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple: **This is not the spirit bomb technique**.

Trunks' new form that is similar to the SSB is solely responsible for pulling in all of that energy and enabling that new sword technique he used against Zamasu.

Considering that we don't have a definition for this form we also don't know it's limitations.

However, I speculate that the new form is a special form of SSB attained when a half human half saiyan can clad themselves in god ki. Doing so enabled him to pull on the ki of other humans to unite into his blade. Which worked because humans are according to Zamasu "made in the image of gods".

That's only a theory but fact of the matter is that what we saw was not Trunks using the spirit bomb.

Comment: In episode 67, when talking about Trunks's sword, you can hear Goku saying "Genki dama" in japanese

Comment: In ep 67 Goku says `Your sword was like a Spirit Bomb there!`. In response Trunks said `It's thanks to everyone, everyone's power defeated him.` From those statements, it's a 50-50 chance that there was actually some different grade of the spirit bomb that relied only on human will. As we can recall from Goku's battle with Vegeta, Freeza, and Kid Buu. The spirit bomb has the ability to draw on power of every form of energy. Plants, trees, grass, and even moons and stars. But Trunks' only used the remaining humans on earth. I still think my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with your question: You think Trunks did a spirit bomb technique. The fact is though that he did NOT do it.

The spirit bomb formed without HIS interference at all.

So what happened? Think about the spirit bomb when Goku uses it. He ASKS all life forms to give him their energy. And they do it. That is  when the spirit bomb forms.

In this case though the people of earth put all their hopes, all their strength into Trunks and wanted to support him in his last fight. So in essence the "spirit bomb" was not formed by Trunks but by the people themselves when they  wanted to support him. As they "just" gave him their energy (out of their own without a need to be asked).

Thus Trunks did nothing and there was no technique invovled. The spirit bomb was just the gathering of all the energy the people gave up themselves to help him.

Comment: In episode 67, when talking about Trunks's sword, you can hear Goku saying "Genki dama" in japanese

Comment: @pablo as it in essence is one. It is the very same principle. BUT as you can see when Trunks looks up he is surprised and confused until he gets it from his sense of KI what it is. The concentrated energy of the life forms on earth. Which is as I said what Goku always asks for and ppl give him when he forms one. In this case....it was formed on its own (which is contrary to what we know how a spirit bomb does and CAN work....as who forms the ball?! But seems like either the makers forgot about that...or rule of cool was more important than continuity).

Comment: Now in the last translation I've been, Goku says to Trunks "your sword acted like a genki dama"